# Get in which terminal column I'm writing

Tags: c, terminal

In my C program I would like to know where my cursor is located in terminal. For example, another program could have written something before mine and I would like to know how much space is left before the last column of the terminal, or I could not know the terminal reaction to some special sequences (like colors: I could write it but they are not showed).

Any suggestion?

Edit: it would be better avoiding over complicated solutions like ncurses (ncurses doesn't know where's the cursor directly: it computes its position).

Edit 2: I found a way to do it, but it works only in non-graphical terminals: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/get-cursor-position-in-c-947833/

Edit 3: Nice code and it works well, but it uses /dev/vcsaN (same problem of *Edit 2*): http://dell9.ma.utexas.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?vcs+4

Comment: `int get_column() { printf("\n\r"); return 0; }`

Comment: `bash` is not a terminal.

Comment: @H2CO3 I need to be where it is, not moving the cursor in a new line

Comment: @n.m. Fixed according to http://superuser.com/questions/144666/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-console-and-terminal

Comment: Shells have no columns or cursors.

Comment: This is in no way Bash or shell-related; rather, it's specific to the terminal.

Comment: @n.m. So please tell me how my post could be fixed: I'm here to learn, not to heard "you said it wrong". Thank you.

Comment: It is pretty much fixed now. Anyway I suggest you locate "shell", "bash", "terminal" and "terminal emulator" entries in Wikipedia, just in case.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to use the correct term the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ncurses is a big and powerful library for creating terminal-based text interfaces.

`tputs` is a simple low-level universal function for manipulating terminal capabilities.

Either one could serve your needs.

Comment: `tput` is nice, but I don't know how to use it to get the current position.

Comment: My memory has failed me, it's tputs, not tput, and it's a bit trickier than I thought, and it is a part of ncurses anyway. So nothing is gained by using it. Sticking with getyx is probably wise.

Comment: By the way, with tput is possible!
`stty -echo; tput u7; read -d R pos; stty echo; echo ${pos#??}`
The same thing works if I use `echo -ne "\e[6n"`
Now I've to understand how to get this data in a C program.

Comment: tput is an executable command, tputs is a function in a library.

Comment: In fact, in order to use `getyx` you have to switch all your output to Ncurses. Ncurses never asks the terminal about the cursor position, it maintains its own (it starts from a known position and it always knows where each operation moves the cursor). If you want to ask the terminal, use the `u7` capability like you've done, but in C. `tput u7` is `putp(tigetstr("u7"))`, and turning echo on/off is demoed [here](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/tty/no_echo.c.html). Note that not all terminals are capable of this (Linux terminal emulators are OK).

Comment: Is not possible to get directly the value of "\e[6n"? This works without ncurses. Which programs do this substitution?

Comment: Terminal capabilities is a database, `u7` is the key, `tigetstr` is the look-up operator, `\e[6n` is the value. The database is normally at `/usr/share/terminfo`, but see the ENVIRONMENT section of `man curses`. The database format is described in `man terminfo`, it is easy to parse.

Comment: `echo -ne "\e[6n"` provides the same value, but I suppose that it doesn't depend on ncurses, right?

Comment: This value is terminal-specific, you are supposed to use the terminal database to find out the value for the current terminal. Ncurses parses the database for you but it's not hard to do it without ncurses too. Though most terminals that support this function will probably have `\e[6n` there, this is not guaranteed. So it's recommended to parse it.

Comment: The database is provided by ncurses, so it would be the same. As you can see in my last answer edit, I'm trying to understand how to do without it. If I will not succeed, in a couple of days I accept an answer here, because initially I didn't ask for a ncurses-less solution.

Comment: No it's not provided by ncurses. It's used by ncurses and also by many other libraries and programs.

Comment: You're right, it's my distribution that pack it with ncurses.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using ncurses' [`getyx()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/curs_getyx).

Comment: It seems that it could only used within a ncurses program, while I need to look at the contest. Maybe I'm wrong (I don't use ncurses).

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli: for terminal handling, `curses` is the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not optimal because it refers to /dev/vcsa*. Hope this could help someone else.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    char *device = "/dev/vcsa2";
    struct {unsigned char lines, cols, x, y;} scrn;
    fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror(device);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    (void) read(fd, &scrn, 4);
    printf("%d %d\n", scrn.x, scrn.y);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you are supposed to remember where you've left the cursor.

However, most terminals do respond to `DSR`; Device Status Request. By sending

```
CSI 6 n
```

you'll receive a `CPR`; cursor position report, in the form of

```
CSI Pl;Pc R
```

where `Pl` and `Pc` give the cursor line and column number, indexed from 1.

Comment: `printf()` is traditional to send things to the terminal.

Comment: However you normally read terminal input. Plenty of ways. Entirely manually with `termios`+`read`, or some sort of wrapping library. E.g. my `libtermkey` which I wrote largely for things like this.

Comment: I'm able to do it with bash using read (as you can see in the other comment), but not in C in a virtual terminal. Could you provide an example?